# Outlook/Exchange RoomFinder (w/ Lex)

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I'm an intern and I've been tasked with creating a RoomFinder API for Outlook that works with Amazon's Lex/Lambda to find a location and schedule meetings given a list of participants. The API is supposed to be able to pull the calendars from Outlook for the individual participants, find a time that works for all of them and a location with a proper seating capacity, and then schedule the meeting+add it to the calendars of those involved. I have a pretty good understanding of how Lex works and have created my own functions using Lambda before but I don't even know where to begin when it comes to pulling the calendars from Outlook for the participants.

I have been trying to get an idea of how to go about this for a few days now and found some information on Outlook's REST API which it sounds like can be used to gather some of the needed information but I'm not sure how to actually begin doing that. Here are links to a few of those pages:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#RegAuthConverged

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643730(v=exchg.150).aspx

I also managed to find a few pages on GitHub of similar, more basic scripts using Python to acquire things like Room Availability from Outlook but I couldn't get any of those to work. I don't have enough reputation to post more links but if seeing those would help I can maybe comment them later.

I'm really looking for any advice on where to begin or tips on how to get this done. I think I may be on the right track with the REST API idea but I have no clue how to actually use it or set it up.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are just now rolling out a new REST API to list the roomsIDs(findrooms). You can use this in conjunction with the findmeetingtimes API to schedule meetings. Please take a look at the REST API docs here(remember to choose *beta* in the top-right)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#GetMeetingRooms